# Deserialize list of objects with list

Tags: c#, xml, list, xml-deserialization

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CallEvents xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CallEvent>
    <Time>2014-02-24T06:44:27.12</Time>
    <Type>Inner</Type>
    <Fs>
      <StrPair>
        <Key>Name</Key>
        <Value>Call1</Value>
      </StrPair>
      <StrPair>
        <Key>Owner</Key>
        <Value>Ali</Value>
      </StrPair>
    </Fs>
  </CallEvent>
  <CallEvent>
    <Time>2014-02-24T06:44:29.089</Time>
    <Type>Outer</Type>
    <Fs>
      <StrPair>
        <Key>Name</Key>
        <Value>Call2</Value>
      </StrPair>
      <StrPair>
        <Key>Id</Key>
        <Value>3242</Value>
      </StrPair>
      <StrPair>
        <Key>Another</Key>
        <Value>123</Value>
      </StrPair>
    </Fs>
  </CallEvent>
</CallEvents>
```

I tried to deserialize it, but it doesn't want to deserialize list `Fs`. I get `CallEvents` with `CallEvent` items, and members of `CallEvent` filled with correct values except list `Fs`. The list `Fs` is empty. Why?
What do I do wrong?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xmlFile = "call_events.xml";
        CallEvents events = CallEvents.OpenFromXmlFile(xmlFile);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class CallEvent
{
    [XmlElement]
    public DateTime Time;
    [XmlElement]
    public CallEventType Type;

    public CallEvent()
    {
        this.Fields = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    [XmlArray("Fs"), XmlArrayItem("StrPair")]
    public List<StrPair> Fs
    {
        get
        {
            var list = new List<StrPair>();
            foreach (var pair in Fields)
            {
                list.Add(new StrPair(pair.Key, pair.Value));
            }
            return list;
        }
        set
        {
            Fields.Clear();
            foreach (var dictPair in value)
            {
                Fields.Add(dictPair.Key, dictPair.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Fields;

    public void ParseFields(List<LogMessage> eventLogMessages)
    {
        int eventLogMessagesCount = eventLogMessages.Count;
        this.Fields.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < eventLogMessagesCount; i++)
        {
            LogMessage logMessage = eventLogMessages[i];
            int pos = logMessage.Message.IndexOf(": ");
            if(pos == -1)
                continue;
            string fieldName = logMessage.Message.Substring(0, pos);
            pos+=2;
            string fieldValue = logMessage.Message.Substring(pos);
            if (this.Fields.ContainsKey(fieldName))
            {
                this.Fields[fieldName] += ("\r\n" + fieldValue);
            }
            else
            {
                this.Fields.Add(fieldName, fieldValue);
            }
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1} | ", Type, Time);
        foreach (var pair in Fields)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}, ", pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class StrPair
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public string Key;
        [XmlElement]
        public string Value;

        public StrPair() { }

        public StrPair(string key, string value)
        {
            Key = key;
            Value = value;
        }
    }
}

[XmlRoot("CallEvents")]
public class CallEvents : List<CallEvent>
{
    static public CallEvents OpenFromXmlFile(string xmlFileName)
    {
        CallEvents callEvents;// = new CallEvents();
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CallEvents));
        XmlReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(xmlFileName);
        try
        {
            callEvents = (CallEvents)ser.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        }
        finally
        {
            xmlReader.Close();
        }
        return callEvents;
    }

    public void SaveToXmlFile(string xmlFileName)
    {
        XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        xmlWriterSettings.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
        XmlWriter xmlWriter = null;
    tryAgain:
        try
        {
            xmlWriter = XmlTextWriter.Create(xmlFileName, xmlWriterSettings);
            ser.Serialize(xmlWriter, this);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult dr = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Couldn't serialize to XML. Details: " + ex.Message, "Error", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Retry)
            {
                goto tryAgain;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (xmlWriter != null)
            {
                xmlWriter.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"What do I do wrong?"_ - you're ignoring the exception.

Comment: @CodeCaster What exception? It runs without any exceptions.

Comment: How can we tell you are doing wrong if you don't actually tell us the problem?

Comment: Then what happens when you call this code, and how exactly do you call it? What is _"it doesn't want to deserialize list"_, what **does** happen?

Comment: @James My problem is: the member "Fs" of class "CallEvent" is empty and not filled with values from XML.

Comment: @CodeCaster sorry. I forgot to show how I call this code. I added it in my question.

Comment: @JaroslavKadlec This code is only for example and I deleted catch blocks to make the code more clear. And exceptions are not ignored in those blocks.

Comment: If you remove the custom `get`/`set` implementation of the `Fs` property does it work?

Comment: @James a big thanks! I didn't think, that because of custom get set implementation property will not work. I deleted custom implementation and now it filled with items!

Comment: @AnatoliiGumennyi if you need to control deserialization (to populate your dictionary) then you can have your `CallEvent` class implement the `IXmlSerializable` and override the `ReadXml` method.

Answer (score -1):

I havn'e used this in a while so the code might need some touching up.

```
CallEvents events;

using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("call_events.xml"))
{
    XmlDeserializer deSerializer = new XmlDeserializer(typeof(CallEvents));
    events = (CallEvents)deSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```